# VB.NET TabControl Web Browser?

Tags: vb.net

I'm a bit new to this, but I'm working on a web browser with tabbed browsing, however..

When a new tab is created, it creates a web browser in it - but I want a function called when the browser is finished loading. I can't create a private sub inside a function, So I am not sure what I should do. Any Ideas?

My Code:

```
Function addtab()
    Dim myTabPage As New TabPage()
    Dim theweb As New WebBrowser

    myTabPage.Text = "TabPage Test" & (TabControl1.TabPages.Count + 1)
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage)

    theweb.GoHome()
    theweb.Parent = myTabPage
    theweb.Visible = True
    theweb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Return True
End Function
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to create a new webBrowser object, dock it in the new tabPage you make and then have the webBrowser do something when it's finished loading, correct?

What about something like this...

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    addtab()
End Sub

Function addtab()
    Dim myTabPage As New TabPage()
    Dim theweb As New WebBrowser()
    AddHandler theweb.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf Run_Me_On_Load)
    myTabPage.Text = "TabPage Test" & (TabControl1.TabPages.Count + 1)
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage)
    theweb.Navigate("http://justinchoponis.com")
    theweb.Parent = myTabPage
    theweb.Visible = True
    theweb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Return True
End Function


Public Sub Run_Me_On_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Finished loading")
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I love you! thanks! :D You are amazzzinngg - I never thought this was possible!